# Magento white page at front and backend

Tags: php, magento

After customizing some files last week, both the back end and front end of the site I’m developing for went blank. I have already searched the internet and tried out some possible solutions, but none of them works.

Somehow I can’t manage to show any error message. I already uncommented `ini_set(’display_errors’, 1);,` changed `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` into `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and I tried even more possible solutions. 
I also edited the memory to 128M, changed some settings in php.ini, changed `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml`. Nothing seems to work.

I seriously have no idea how I can solve this, so that’s why I’m here. I hope someone can help me. If you need more information, please ask, I don’t really know what’s necessary to answer my question.

---

After adding the following lines to index.php I managed to get error messages:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set(’display_errors’, 1); 
ini_set(‘memory_limit’, ’256M’);
```

The error I get is:

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/cheapas/public_html/index.php, line 39
```

Trace:

```
#0 /home/cheapas/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true) 
#1 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader(’Content-Type’, ‘text/html; char...’) 
#2 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse() 
#3 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php(204): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse() 
#4 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(166): Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite->rewrite() 
#5 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
#6 /home/cheapas/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#7 /home/cheapas/public_html/index.php(91): Mage::run(’’, ‘store’) 
#8 {main}
```

Guess what, line 39 is: ini_set(‘memory_limit’, ’256M’);

When I delete this line I get a blank page again, so that doesn’t solve anything. Does anyone have an idea on solving this? Thanks!

---

As you may have understood, I actually can get error messages to show when I force an error by adding an unknown or uncomplete line to my index.php. Somehow there is a problem which doesn’t want to show up.

Comment: FYI, Magento has its [own StackExchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Didn't know that, going to try it there too then, thanks!